# Is there some stream "pipe" class in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, stream, async-await, pipe

I programed a FastCGI library for C#. This was before the time of async/await. Now I'm programming a version 2 of this library with performance in mind. Therefore i'm using IOCP by using socket.ReceiveAsync. (Note: `ReceiveAsync` has nothing to do with `await`/`async`. I want to use `ReceiveAsync`.)

However it is possible for the user of the library to answer an incoming request by not specifying Content-Length-header. This leads to a situation where the library needs to collect all outgoing traffic until all data are available or the user specifies Content-Length.

My old version of this library realized this with a self-written class `LocalPipe`. `LocalPipe` is just a Stream where you can write datas to and then read datas from it. If there are not enough datas available the read-method is blocking.

While `LocalPipe` is blocking the calling thread is also blocking and therefore not released while waiting for new data. This leads to a "one connection/one thread" design, at least while waiting for data from `LocalPipe`.

**My question is: Is there already a class (as NuGet package or in the .NET framework itself) which implements something like my `LocalPipe` class but which will "block" without keeping the calling thread in use?**

I'm **not** in search of the regular `Task`-Pattern for `await` unless it really would avoid the use of unnecessary `Thread`s/`Task`s and context-switches. Currently the only way to implement this class "thread consuming friendly" seems to make heavy use of `ExecutionContext` and/or `SynchronizationContext` while implementing an awaitable pattern by my self. It would be nice if I can just evade this.

Comment: Did you try the `BlockingCollection` with corresponding generic type? Or, maybe, `MemoryStream`?

Comment: Both are **not** what i'm looking for. `BlockingCollection` is a `Collection` while `MemoryStream` is not `async` and doesn't block when the end of stream has been reached. However, I solved the "problem" by implementing my own pipe. I keep this question open, maybe someone knows an open library for this.

Edit: Just before someone mentions this: I know of *Async-methods coming from stream. **But** according to referencesource the `MemoryStream` just makes these `async`-calls blocking by directly calling (for instance) `Read` within.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, meanwhile there is:

[System.IO.Pipelines](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-io-pipelines-high-performance-io-in-net/)